# Xcode IDE crashes when performing any action

Tags: ios, xcode

I can launch an Xcode project, but the second I try to do anything, e.g. toggle automatic signing, link a library, even change the build number or ANYTHING, Xcode crashes. The only hint I get as to why is this error on "Xcode quit unexpectedly"

> UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[PBXFileReference realReference]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbc8f52ee10

Something is corrupted. I thought it was related to the `pbxproj` file I don't know if that's the case. There are no merge conflicts. Does anybody have any clue as to what is happening? I want to rip my hair out but I'm bald.

Things I've tried:

- Updating my system software
- Deleting and reinstalling Xcode entirely
- The status quo of deleted Derived Data and cleaning the project/builds

**Note:**

- Other Xcode projects are launching fine and I am able to navigate the
  IDE. It's only this project.
- It seems to be Xcode version agnostic. So far I've confirmed it crashes when changing anything on Xcode 9.4.1 and 8.3.3.

I can provide additional context around the project upon request.

Comment: `git bisect` till you find the project change that broke it. You might be able to nail it down http://webchick.net/node/99

Comment: Looks to be related to third party libs/frameworks

Comment: I have had this a few times. Clean the project (`command + shift + k`), restart Xcode, and then make sure you are in the `Standard inspector`, rather than the `Assistant editor` or the `Version editor`. Now you can navigate through your files without problem.